# Mailing don't send after update to 5.68

Tags: wordpress, mailing

Since i have updated to 5.68, mailing don't sent any mail...
SMTP Test ok
No error when test mail from mailing but no email receps..

Anyone life that?

Comment: Can you check the scehdule job to see if there are any errors?

Comment: "civicrm/ConfigAndLog/" is worth checking as well.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. It's really surprising... no errors in the log or in the planned tasks.
I am testing with version 5.66: email received
Then the test with 5.68: nothing
However, nothing has changed in my configuration and the SMTP test works in both versions.
Worse, the sending notification is positive (green popup); incomprehensible

Comment: I assume this is a local smtp process? Have you reviewed the log for your MTA (Exim or Postfix, or whatever you're using)? It sounds like Civi is making contact with your MTA, but your MTA is not able to get the mail to it's destination.